# Сложный запрос в PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица с основными полями created_at тип timestamp и attention_parameter тип boolean. То есть периодически этот параметр становится в тру и после идет несколько записей с этим параметром. Потом этот параметр становится в false и потом несколько записей с этим параметром в false. Нужно найти первую запись в группе записей с этим параметром в true.

То есть

1. 10.12.21 false
2. 11.12.21 false
3. 12.12.21 false
4. 13.12.21 true
5. 14.12.21 true
6. 15.12.21 true
7. 16.12.21 false
8. 17.12.21 false
9. 18.12.21 false
10. 19.12.21 true
11. 20.12.21 true
12. 21.12.21 false
13. 22.12.21 false
14. 23.12.21 true - вот эту запись - первую в группе с true
15. 24.12.21 true
16. 23.12.21 true

Comment: Тебе надо создать окно `WINDOW ... AS` (равное всей таблице) упорядоченное по дате https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html и потом для каждой строки в окне смотреть предыдущее значение флага `LAG` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-window.html и сравнивать с текущим

Comment: Я бы написал запрос, но поскольку тебе влом было предоставить операторы `CREATE TABLE` и `INSERT INTO`, то мне тоже влом делать твою работу за тебя.